# Django unable to resolve the import type

Tags: django, python-3.x, pycharm

Iam a newbie learning django iam struck here can someone help on this.

i followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMTVAIVrdtM
Iam using pycharm IDE, created on the similar lines but still iam getting the error.

```
from poll import view as poll_views  ### Getting error in this line .....----<<<<<<<

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(''.poll_views.home,name='home'),
    path('create/'.poll_views.create, name='create'),
    path('vote/<poll_id>'.poll_views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('results/<poll_id>'.poll_views.results, name='results'),



]

views.py

    from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'poll/home.html',context)

def create(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'poll/create.html',context)

def vote(request, poll_id):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'poll/vote.html',context)

def results(request, poll_id):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'poll/results.html',context)
```

On terminal

```
(test) C:\Users\Learner\projects\poll_project>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Learner\projects\poll_project\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Learner\projects\poll_project\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Learner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Learner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Learner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Learner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\Learner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Learner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 64, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Learner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Learner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Learner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Learner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Learner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Learner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Learner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Learner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Learner\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "c:\users\Learner\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1021, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 998, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 977, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Learner\projects\poll_project\poll_project\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from poll import view as poll_views
ImportError: cannot import name 'view' from 'poll' (C:\Users\Learner\projects\poll_project\poll\__init__.py)
```

Please find the project folder screenshot below.

this is my folder structure

[image: Project folder structure]

Can someone please help me where iam going wrong ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

url takes following argument path(route, view, name{optional})
but you are giving path(route.view, name)

replace . after route by ,

Comment: Hi Sheeram_prajapat,anuragal  thanks for the reply...  corrected my views.py... migrattions worked, but still  getting ( import poll.views as poll_views ) on poll iam getting error as no module named poll, instead of that autocomplete is showing poll_project...  what can be wrong.. i followed the same directory structure as they explained in video

Comment: Your project name is poll_project instead of poll ? If yes, then change poll to poll_project in urls.py file of main project

Comment: Hi Anuragal/Shreeram, Thank you to both, Created a new poll page freshly still the same error was there for import/ but was able to successfully create a poll page ... @Shreeram accepting your answer as it was the primary mistake i have done.

Answer (score 3):

The import statement should be like

If want to import specific view

```
from poll.views import <nameoftheview> as poll_views
```

Or if you want to import all the views

```
import poll.views as poll_views
```

Update: Correct error in your `urls.py` (also pointed out by @sheraram)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('create/', poll_views.create, name='create'),
    path('vote/<poll_id>', poll_views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('results/<poll_id>', poll_views.results, name='results'),
    path('', poll_views.home,name='home'),
]
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.

Comment: i have tried that but it is unable to identify as from poll.views import.... instead of that it is accepting as from poll_project import poll ( but still iam getting error                                                                                                            as      File "C:\Users\Learner\projects\poll_project\poll_project\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    from poll_project import poll_project
ImportError: cannot import name 'poll_project' from 'poll_project' (C:\Users\s5114509\projects\poll_project\poll_project\__init__.py)

can you please

Comment: Try `import poll.views as poll_views`, this is what you need. Still facing problem then paste your `views.py` code

Comment: unable to resolve getting same error so uploaded the views.py code

Comment: Have you added `poll` as an App in `settings.py`? I advise you to follow this tutorial - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/, it is similar to what you are following

Comment: sorry, i did not add that,  but now i have added in settings after that ran the python manage.py migrate ....  for that getting error as (     path(''.poll_views.home,name='home'),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'poll_views'  ) and also unable to resolve the import error
.

Comment: i had followed the same tutorial , got success but got struck in connecting the sqlinte3 database, so freshly i have started this tutorial